# how to extract the description of a video from youtube using php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

how to extract the description of a video from youtube using php?

if possible with the formatting of line breaks.

want to extract plain text it will save to txt with php.

thank you

Comment: You could do it as worsnupd below suggests, I would recommend looking into the YouTube Data API:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api

Comment: so they can understand my question, I need to get the description of a video from youtube through the id of the video and save this description in a custom field with the same formatting youtube

Answer (score 2):

You can use the YouTube Data API.

Use this URL to get a json array for the specific video-id

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KQdDiW_C2E4?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFeedCallback

`KQdDiW_C2E4` is the video-id
`v=2` tells the server to use v2 of the API
`alt=json-in-script` tells the API to return a json array

If you `json_decode` the returned array, you will find the description in
`array->entry->media$group->media$description`

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers I found online for this question helped me. This is what I did instead:

```
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status'), TRUE );
$description = nl2br( $json['items'][0]['snippet']['description'] );
```

You can get the Google API key from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) (Only steps 1 and 2 need to be followed since you only need the API key).

The [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function is used to convert newlines into line breaks.

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could request a youtube video's html document using php's [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function and then search for the `<div>` containing the description and extract it that way.

I just looked at a youtube video page, and it looks like the description is inside the `<p id="eow-description">` tag, although it is obviously not guaranteed to stay that way.

EDIT: I didn't realize Youtube provided an API. It would obviously be cleaner to use their API and ask for the information you want than to try and parse their html pages. Thanks to Sander for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following class to access YouTube.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6336-PHP-Retrieve-information-about-videos-in-YouTube.html

A quick example of how it works;

```
<?
$obj = new youtube;
$obj->url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B7s01DpBTg";
$obj->player("480","385");
print $info["description"];

?>
```

Comment: this is a great middle class however the only problem is that it loses the formatting description, is to retain the formatting of line breaks