# YouTube Data API - How I Get auto generated Transcript using API in PHP?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been attempting to access auto-generated transcripts for YouTube videos using the YouTube Data API in PHP, but I haven't had much success. I've reviewed several resources, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065772/18243614, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186001/18243614, and [Getting YouTube auto-transcript from API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867732/getting-youtube-auto-transcript-from-api) but I'm still facing issues.

Could someone provide a clear example or guide on how to use the YouTube Data API with PHP specifically to obtain auto-generated transcripts for YouTube videos? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!